# Using SummaryStatistics for binning data representation

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a data representation using bins (featureReduction/Type binning).

I would like to be able to use the summary statistics function to obtain the Min and Max values. The idea is to use them as STOPS in my representation.

I have tried the following code:

```
const featureLayer =

const featureReduction =

const map = new Map({
    basemap: "gray-vector",
    layers: [featureLayer]
    });

  const view = new MapView({
  container: "viewDiv",
  map: map,
  center: [2.333333,48.866667],
  scale: 144447,
  constraints: {
      snapToZoom: false
  }
  });
const my_stats = summaryStatistics({
    layer: featureLayer,
    view,
    field: "aggregate",
    forBinning: true
  });
```

How can I use the SummaryStatistics function before declaring the Map and View (as I have tried but without success)  ?